# Rubygems, gemspec, possible rvm error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm

I got an error message when upgrading to Rails 3.2 and Rubygems. As advised on stackoverflow, I ran `gem update --system` that upgraded Rubygems to 1.8.24. After this update I ran a simple `rails s` command and I get this persistent error with every command I run.

My RVM version is: 1.17.7

My Ruby versions is: `ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]`

When I run `bundle install`, I get an error:

```
"Could not find twitter-1.6.0 in any of the sources"
```

When I run `rails -v`, I get an error:

```
could not find rack-1.2.3. run bundle install.
```

I think I might have also installed gems with the `sudo` command at some point, which may have screwed up my process. Is there a way to check? or correct that?

```
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/actionmailer-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d85b5f0> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/actionpack-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d93d6a8> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/activemodel-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d89b5b0> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/activerecord-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d9ddc48> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/activeresource-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d9cdca8> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/rails-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d908d68> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/railties-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8c034468> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/actionmailer-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d85b5f0> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/actionpack-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d93d6a8> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/activemodel-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d89b5b0> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/activerecord-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d9ddc48> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/activeresource-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d9cdca8> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/rails-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d908d68> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/railties-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8c034468> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/actionmailer-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d85b5f0> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/actionpack-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d93d6a8> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/activemodel-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d89b5b0> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/activerecord-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d9ddc48> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/activeresource-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d9cdca8> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/rails-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d908d68> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/railties-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8c034468> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/actionmailer-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d85b5f0> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/actionpack-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d93d6a8> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/activemodel-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d89b5b0> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/activerecord-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d9ddc48> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/activeresource-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d9cdca8> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/rails-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8d908d68> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/railties-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fad8c034468> 3.2.0"]
script/rails:6:in `require': no such file to load -- rails/commands (LoadError)
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think you installed your Rails using sudo, try:

```
ls -al ~ | grep .rvm
```

`~` is the shortcut for `$HOME`, so the command will list your home directory, pipe the output to `grep` which will search for a listing containing `.rvm`.

Your `.rvm` folder should be owned by you, which would look like `rdo staff` in the listing. We want to take both your user ID and the group value, which is `staff` by default, and tell the system to make you the owner of all files in your `.rvm` directory.

```
sudo chown +r jdo:staff ~/.rvm
```

That will recursively descend into `.rvm` and reset the file and folder ownership back to you for all the contents inside your RVM directory, including the installed Rubies and their gems.

Don't go doing that command willy-nilly over the drive or your system can get really upset, but for that directory, or ones you know should belong to your user, that's the command to use... just be careful to point at the right directory when you pull the trigger.